# I want to get value inside my String JsonObject

Tags: android, arrays, json

```
    try {
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
        String status = jobj.getString("status");
        String error = jobj.getString("result");

        if(status == "1"){
            builder.setTitle("Server Message");
            builder.setMessage("Please validate your ID in registered email.");

        }else if(status == "0")
        {
            builder.setTitle("Server Message");
            builder.setMessage(error);
        }else{
            builder.setTitle("Server Message");
            builder.setMessage(response);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

my response is {"status":"1","result":"true")
But I can't do if else to the "status" mean I can't get value of "1" inside the status.

Comment: You should create POJO class for your json response and you should access it  with your object property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two mistakes

1. Getting integer and boolean as string
2. Comparing string with `==`

Do this

```
int status = jobj.getInt("status");
Boolean error = jobj.getBoolean("result");

if(status == 1){
    builder.setTitle("Server Message");
    builder.setMessage("Please validate your ID in registered email.");
}else if(status == 0) 
{
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: @Avezan It would auto parse. Check the code of `getInt(String name)` in `JSONObject` class

Comment: yes, in your attempt it will auto parse, not in his. Anyway answer is right +1.

Comment: Thanks for +1. That is OP's mistake and we should suggest better solution if available.

Answer (score 0):

"==" is reference compare.
So, replace "==" to equals()

```
status.equals("1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

By using String

```
 String status = jobj.getString("status");
    String error = jobj.getString("result");

   if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
      builder.setTitle("Server Message");
     builder.setMessage("Please validate your ID in registered email.");

    }else if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
        // your other code.
}
```